# How to install php 5 on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, php5

I need advice how to install php5 on this os. There is only php7 package available, but for my system php5 is required.

Comment: No versions of PHP 5 are currently supported. Time to put in the work to upgrade. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: the web application I use only supports php 5 unfortunately

Comment: "Time to put in the work to upgrade."

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you don't. [PHP 5.6 reached end-of-life in December 2018](https://php.net/eol.php).

[For the time being](https://www.patreon.com/posts/php-5-6-and-php-25226448), [deb.sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/) still has builds of PHP 5.6 available. However, these builds will only be available as long as Microsoft continues to maintain [the upstream repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/php-src), so you should take immediate steps to make your code run on current versions of PHP.

If the code you are running is supplied by a third party and no updates for PHP 7 compatibility are available, start looking for alternatives. PHP 7 has been available since 2015; a failure to provide updated code for 4+ years is a sign that the application is not being maintained appropriately.